# No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

Tags: java, oracle, maven, tomcat, jdbc

I have that error, when I try to get DB connection. I can connect to DB, when i run my app as Java app, but when I deploy my app at Tomcat server I get that error. How can I fix this?

P.S. I use maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, SO magic happened. I just add that code  before connection - and it works

```java
DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check your war file.During build process jdbc jar required for connection is missing.Please check scope of  jdbc jar in your maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the possible reasons:-

1.Check the  package to refer OracleDriver class .It should be

`oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

2.Download the ojdbc14.jar file

then right click on the folder you are working on and go to its properties

3. JDBC URL should be like this

"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all the library files in a lib folder inside your project. For example 
  -Project
  ---src
  ---lib
  ---Resource
Then add the libraries to classpath. The best idea is to use Maven

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat needs either a classes12.jar or ojdbc6.jar file in the $approot/WEB-INF/lib/ folder - don't forget to deploy it there.
That should take care of your missing thin driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this dependency isn't hosted in maven. You'll need to download the jar, install it in maven and reference the dependency in your pom. This site explains each step.

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/